# how to resolve facebook access toke expire issue?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how to resolve facebook access toke expire issue?

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/user-id/friends?fields=id,picture.type(large),name&access_token=

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired on Monday, 20-Feb-17 10:55:58 PST. The current time is Monday, 27-Mar-17 04:04:19 PDT.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 463,
      "fbtrace_id": "Gn6VQOcN18D"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your session expired it means you need to re-login and receive a new session

Alternatively you can request a new session before your old one expired and not perform a re-login

Comment: I'm using facebook integration in my application.In my application is one of the part is facebook friend list requesting is there after 3 month my application it's giving lik this error { "error": { "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired on Monday, 20-Feb-17 10:55:58 PST. The current time is Monday, 27-Mar-17 04:04:19 PDT.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 190, "error_subcode": 463, "fbtrace_id": "Gn6VQOcN18D" } }

Comment: Yeah and my answer stay the same, your session expired as you haven't requested a new one